# Run-time error '1004' Unable to set the Text Property of Range

Tags: excel, runtime-error, vba

I am trying to store data from "details" sheet into strings from different columns to different strings for every row in a linear manner and then assign the strings the same value 51 times in Cells of other sheet named "output".

```
Option Explicit

Sub Arrange()
Dim FinalRow, FinalRow1 As Long
Dim ws, wr As Worksheet
Dim strCN, strAdd, strCity, strState, strZip, strPhone, strWeb As String
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Dim i, j As Long


Set ws = Sheets("details")
FinalRow = ws.Range("A900000").End(xlUp).Row

For j = 2 To FinalRow

    strCN = Cells(j, "A")
    strAdd = Cells(j, "H")
    strCity = Cells(j, "I")
    strState = Cells(j, "J")
    strZip = Cells(j, "K")
    strPhone = Cells(j, "R")
    strWeb = Cells(j, "U")

    Set wr = Sheets("output")
    FinalRow1 = wr.Range("A900000").End(xlUp).Row
    For i = FinalRow1 To FinalRow1 + 51
        With Sheets("output")
            Cells(i, "A").Text = strCN       'Error Line
            Cells(i, "B").Text = strAdd
            Cells(i, "C").Text = strCity
            Cells(i, "D").Text = strState
            Cells(i, "E").Text = strZip
            Cells(i, "F").Text = strPhone
            Cells(i, "G").Text = strWeb
        End With
    Next i
Next j

End Sub
```

Comment: Change the `.text` to `.value`

Comment: Already did gives me subscript out of range error

Comment: When it breaks, what is the value of 'i'? and what is the value of strCN?

Comment: okay it ran but no change in the sheet "output" and the "i" value is Empty

Comment: I failed to notice that you are in a with statement.  put a '.' in fornt of the cells...

Comment: Sorry but That gives me an "invalid or unqualified reference" error on line just after the first For loop

Comment: NB: `.Text` is a read-only property :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per our conversation above.  I have made the changes I suggested.

The last problem was that the details sheet was not being called and if the other sheet was active at the time it was looking at empty cells.

```
Dim FinalRow, FinalRow1 As Long
Dim ws, wr As Worksheet
Dim strCN, strAdd, strCity, strState, strZip, strPhone, strWeb As String
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Dim i, j As Long


Set ws = Sheets("details")
FinalRow = ws.Range("A900000").End(xlUp).Row

For j = 2 To FinalRow
    With ws
        strCN = .Cells(j, "A")
        strAdd = .Cells(j, "H")
        strCity = .Cells(j, "I")
        strState = .Cells(j, "J")
        strZip = .Cells(j, "K")
        strPhone = .Cells(j, "R")
        strWeb = .Cells(j, "U")
    End With
    Set wr = Sheets("output")
    FinalRow1 = wr.Range("A900000").End(xlUp).Row
    For i = FinalRow1 To FinalRow1 + 51
        With Sheets("output")
            .Cells(i, "A").Value = strCN       'Error Line
            .Cells(i, "B").Value = strAdd
            .Cells(i, "C").Value = strCity
            .Cells(i, "D").Value = strState
            .Cells(i, "E").Value = strZip
            .Cells(i, "F").Value = strPhone
            .Cells(i, "G").Value = strWeb
        End With
    Next i
Next j
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
```

Comment: Do you mind sharing your working file via dropbox or something please for some reasons I can't get it to work

Comment: just email me scott.craner@gmail.com and I will send it to you.